# Multiple tcp connections in single thread with using libevent or boost::asio. It's possible?

Tags: c++, c, boost-asio, libevent

Is it possible to use libevent for create multiple tcp connections to different servers in one thread? Could you write a sample implementation of such a task?

I have done so, but not sure that it's right:

```
...
int num_of_connect = 5; /*for example*/
struct event_base *evbase;
struct bufferevent *bev[num_of_connect];
struct sockaddr_in sin[num_of_connect];
evbase = event_base_new();

for(int i=0;i<=(num_of_connect-1);i++){

   sin[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
   sin[i].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(/*some addr*/);
   sin[i].sin_port = htons(/*some port*/);

   bev[i] = bufferevent_socket_new(evbase, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);

   bufferevent_setcb(bev[i], cb_evread, cb_evwrite, cb_event, NULL);
   bufferevent_socket_connect(bev[i], (struct sockaddr *)&sin[i], sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
}

event_base_dispatch(evbase);
...
```

In addition, similar can be implemented using the boost::asio? Example?)

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, similar can be
>   implemented using the boost::asio?
>   Example?)

Yes, it is entirely possible. This is the basis of the proactor design pattern promoted by Boost.Asio. It achieves concurrency without the use of explicit threads by avoiding blocking operations such as `connect`, `accept`, `read`, and `write`. You might find some of my previous answers useful here

- [Proactor and async_write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554990/proactor-and-async-write/5555392#5555392)
- [Clarification about asynchronous and synchronous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282659/some-clarification-needed-about-synchronous-versus-asynchronous-asio-operations/5291002#5291002)

As Tony pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659385/multiple-tcp-connections-in-single-thread-with-using-libevent-or-boostasio-it/5659798#5659798), the Boost.Asio has fantastic examples explaining the asynchronous concepts in detail. The tutorial, specifically the [asynchronous daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html), is also a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use boost::asio to run in a thread which accepts the connection asynchronously.  There is examples on the [boost::asio documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) which will show you how to setup a server which accepts multiple connections on a single thread.

I'm not familiar with libevent to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use libevent for create multiple tcp connections to different servers in one thread? Could you write a sample implementation of such a task?

Yes, its possible.

You could also create a server that listened on multiple ports with `evconnlistener_new_bind`.

And if you wanted to handle one or more signals, then you could use `evsignal_new` to add signals to the event base.

In each case (`bufferevent_socket_new`, `evconnlistener_new_bind` and `evsignal_new`, the callbacks for each event would be likely different.